# New Patch for PayPal Instant Payment Notification (IPN) Changes. Upgrade to 1.9.3.3 or SUPEE-8167 by June 30, 2017 to Avoid Service Disruptions

Tags: magento-1.9, patches, magento1.9.3, magento-1.9.3.3, supee-8167

Today I got this notification in Magento.

> **New Patch for PayPal Instant Payment Notification (IPN) Changes.
>   Upgrade to 1.9.3.3 or SUPEE-8167 by June 30, 2017 to Avoid Service
>   Disruptions – 6/13/2017** As of June 30, 2017, PayPal Instant Payment
>   Notifications will no longer allow you to use HTTP to post messages
>   back to PayPal for verification. To comply with these changes, all
>   merchants using PayPal must upgrade to Community Edition 1.9.3.3 or
>   apply the SUPEE-8167 patch. Updates must be in place by June 30, 2017
>   to avoid any service disruptions. The patch is available on the
>   Community Edition Download Page
>   (https://magento.com/tech-resources/download) and more information is
>   available from PayPal at
>   https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&widgetview=true&id=FAQ1916&viewlocale=en_US

The link https://magento.com/tech-resources/download does not provide me with a link to download Magento 1.9.3.3. I'm also unable to find a download link for or a guide to applying patch SUPEE-8167.

**How can I avoid service disruptions caused by the PayPal Instant Payment Notification (IPN) Changes?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to click the **release archive** tab at https://magento.com/tech-resources/download

**Scroll down** to the bottom of the page for the CE 1.x patches and CE 1.9.3.3 source code downloads.

Apply the patches for CE 1.x as per the Magento documentation here http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/other/ht_install-patches.html

Comment: This is an excellent answer. So it looks like it just changes the PayPal url from https://paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr to https://ipnpb.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr. Does this mean https://paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr will stop working on June 30th?

Comment: @paj My Magento (ver. 1.9.1.0) Website server having SSL install as well SHA256 with TLS1.2 then it is needed to  install this patch or not

Comment: @Narayan I think it depends on which type of paypal payment module you are using. If https is configured for your shop the IPN from paypal should also come via https. To be on the safe side either apply the patch or test from your dev shop with the paypal sandbox.